# What is the lightning bolt gauge on the right side of the screen?

Tags: best-fiends-forever

Sometimes there is a gauge that pops up on the right side of the game, it has a lightning icon. What does this gauge do for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The higher the gauge is, the faster slugs will spawn. During this time you will automatically claim boss prizes and go through levels at a much faster rate. This is to accommodate going through the portal and being back at level 1. Since you're much stronger if you bought some souvenirs, you can kill things much faster.

Here is a quote from the official [Best Fiends Forever Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/BestFiendsForever/comments/59qzjv/what_is_the_gauge_on_the_right_side_of_the_screen/d9b4yas/) account:

> It's the Blitz Meter. Once you become powerful enough (around the beginning of World 2), you’ll enter Blitz Mode, where you literally blast through everything - even Boss Fights! Keep upgrading your Fiends during Blitz to sustain the mode for as long as you can and increase the speed!